# How to port `ranger-cd` function to fish shell

Tags: fish

I have been trying to port the `ranger-cd` function for the [ranger file manager](https://ranger.github.io/) to the [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/). As of 2013, ranger’s `ranger-cd` function looks like this:

```sh
function ranger-cd {
    tempfile='/tmp/chosendir'
    /usr/bin/ranger --choosedir="$tempfile" "${@:-$(pwd)}"
    test -f "$tempfile" &&
    if [ "$(cat -- "$tempfile")" != "$(echo -n `pwd`)" ]; then
        cd -- "$(cat "$tempfile")"
    fi
    rm -f -- "$tempfile"
}

# This binds Ctrl-O to ranger-cd:
bind '"\C-o":"ranger-cd\C-m"'
```

(This function gives a temporary file to ranger file manager to store the last accessed directory so that we can change to that directory after ranger quits.)

Here’s what I have done so far to port the function to fish:

```sh
function ranger-cd
    set tempfile '/tmp/chosendir'
    /usr/bin/ranger --choosedir=$tempfile (pwd)
    test -f $tempfile and
    if cat $tempfile != echo -n (pwd)
        cd (cat $tempfile)
    end
    rm -f $tempfile
end

function fish_user_key_bindings
        bind \co ranger-cd
end
```

When I use this function I get:

```
test: unexpected argument at index 2: 'and'
     1  /home/gokcecat: !=: No such file or directory
cat: echo: No such file or directory
cat: /home/gokce: Is a directory
```

I’m guessing there are still multiple errors in the above code. Does anyone have a working solution for this?

Comment: The **[ranger community wiki](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki)** on GitHub has a Fish version of this function in [Integration with other programs: Changing directories](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Integration-with-other-programs#changing-directories). That’s probably a more official and up-to-date source than this Stack Overflow page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer is based off of gzfrancisco's. However, I fix the "'-a' at index 2" issue, and I also ensure that a new prompt is printed after exiting ranger.

I put the following in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
function ranger-cd                                                               

  set tempfile '/tmp/chosendir'                                                  
  ranger --choosedir=$tempfile (pwd)                                    

  if test -f $tempfile                                                           
      if [ (cat $tempfile) != (pwd) ]                                            
        cd (cat $tempfile)                                                       
      end                                                                        
  end                                                                            

  rm -f $tempfile                                                                

end                                                                              

function fish_user_key_bindings                                                  
    bind \co 'ranger-cd ; commandline -f repaint'                                           
end
```

Comment: It'd be great if this ended up in ranger's documentation. I don't have the energy right now to do that...

Comment: would be awesome if ranger would ship it as /usr/share/doc/ranger/examples/fish_automatic_cd.fish

Comment: There's a bug with this and it would be great if someone could suggest a fix. The bug is that, after exiting ranger, the prompt shows the *old* working directory, not the actual new working directory from which you're leaving ranger. Hitting enter once will show a new prompt with the correct working directory.

Comment: i don't experience this problem in fish 2.2.0 and xfce4-terminal. @chrisdembia

Comment: If you use `fish_vi_key_bindings` then you have to use the `-M insert` flag with the call to bind, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

simpler solution, but it does the same. type in shell:

```
alias ranger 'ranger --choosedir=$HOME/.rangerdir; set RANGERDIR (cat $HOME/.rangerdir); cd $RANGERDIR'
funcsave ranger
```

[alias](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#alias) is a shortcut do define a function. [funcsave](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#funcsave) saves it into `~/.config/fish/functions/ranger.fish`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line.

```
test -f $tempfile and
```

You shuld remove the and because "and" is a conditional execution
http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/user_doc/html/commands.html#and

```
function ranger-cd

  set tempfile '/tmp/chosendir'
  /usr/bin/ranger --choosedir=$tempfile (pwd)

  if test -f $tempfile and cat $tempfile != echo -n (pwd)
    cd (cat $tempfile)
  end

  rm -f $tempfile

end
```

Comment: now I'm getting `test: Expected a combining operator like '-a' at index 2` after exiting the function.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: This does not work for fish unfortunately, but only for bash-compatible shells.

I recently found out that there is another way to accomplish the same end goal, by sourcing the ranger script instead:

```
source ranger
```

When ranger is then exited, it will have changed the working directory into the last visited one.

Comment: Does not seem to work on 1.9.2, /usr/bin/ranger is a python script

Comment: Does not work in the fish shell, which this question is about. With fish 3.4.1 and ranger 1.9.3, `source ranger` results in “No such file or directory”. `source (which ranger)` results in “/usr/local/bin/ranger (line 12): Unsupported use of '='. In fish, please use 'set temp_file "$(mktemp -t "ranger_cd.XXXXXXXXXX")"'.” That error is because the shell syntax inside the `ranger` script file only works with Bash-compatible shells.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane That makes sense, will edit my answer